# Non-graphical terminals take a long time to log in

Tags: command-line, login, text-mode

When I log in using SSH or after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, it takes several seconds after I enter my password to finally show the following:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-28-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
Unable to connect to X server
Unable to connect to X server

user@host:~$
```

What is it doing that causes it to take several seconds to get to a shell prompt? How can I speed it up?

Comment: This usually happens because of resolv.conf issues. What is the domain name of your server? Can it reach that? It is trying to resolv root controllers

Comment: UseDNS=no is the solution for this problem. Change sshd_config.

Answer (score 0):

"What is it doing that causes it to take several seconds to get to a shell prompt?"

It's using RSA to establish a secure, authenticated connection, and then does a Diffie-Hellman ratchet to establish forward security by generating a one-time key. So there's a good deal of security overhead with SSH.

Comment: That wouldn't affect the loading of a local TTY, though, would it? OP said when they press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> it takes several seconds to load the command prompt after they enter their password. I'm thinking it has something to do with the `Unable to connect to X server` errors.

Comment: Maybe, but I experience a similar delay when I ssh into my server, and I get no such errors.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad answer, since it does apply to a lot of people who would ask about a delay, but SSH only takes a short while longer than the text console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) to log in and then both take several seconds to get to the shell prompt for me.